# Проблема взятия производной Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

Хочу взять производную, но выбивает эту ошибку, пишет не может использовать эту переменную, не пойму почему:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что может быть причиной?

Comment: `a = 0.2456`, not `a == 0.2456` :)

Answer (score 0):

`a` - глобальная переменная, нужно локализовать:

`Module[{a},D[f[a,b,c],a]]` или `Module[{a,b,c},D[f[a,b,c],a]]`